# Is there a way to get the height of the ActionBar?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to get the height of the actionbar in pixels or DIPS.
I can only ever return 0;

```
<Page class="page"
  navigatingFrom="onNavigatingFrom"
  navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
<ActionBar id="actionBar" class="action-bar theme-action-bar">
```

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var actionBar = page.getViewById("actionBar");
    var height = actionBar.getActualSize().height;
    //or
    var height = actionBar.height;

}
```

Comment: It is not enough context for a complete answer, but if you execute your code on page `loaded` handler, then you get the correct result (see the console log of [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=87LA6N)). Page widgets simple does not exist on page `navigatingTo` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout,

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var actionBar = page.getViewById("actionBar");
    setTimeout(()=>{
       var height = actionBar.getActualSize().height;
    }, 100);
}
```